# Is there a better way to 'use arguments in a pipes sequence' with xargs?

Tags: bash, xargs

On several occasions I want to use **xargs** generated arguments and use them in an elaborated command pipeline (piping the results through several steps and using).

I typically end up using a **bash -c** with xargs-generated-argument as only argument. E.g:

```
find *.obj | xargs -I{} bash -c 'sha256sum $0 | tee $0.sha256' {}
```

Is there any better or more concise way to do this?

Comment: No, not really.

Comment: in your specific example you might be able to omit the `xargs` altogether - `find` has an `-exec` argument that can run arbitrary commands per result.  You might also want to check to see if passing multiple `FILE` arguments to sha256sum would yield acceptable results (it would provide a "manifest" of checksums, not one per file in another file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is more concise with **GNU Parallel** as follows:

```
find "*.obj" -print0 | parallel -0 sha256sum {} \| tee {}.sha256
```

In addition, it is:

- potentially more performant since it works in parallel across all CPU cores
- debuggable by using `parallel --dry-run ...`
- more informative by using `--bar` or `--eta` to get a progress bar or ETA for completion
- more flexible, since it gives you many predefined variables, such as `{.}` meaning the current file minus its extension, `{/}` meaning "base name" of current file, `{//}` meaning directory of current file and so on